# Qt SDK problems

Tags: qt, compiler-errors

I'm using Qt on Windows 7 and win xp for some months and am still a new user.

I frequently have problems with build a Qt project which I do some changes in the source codes i.e. *.cpp,.. and click build or build/rebuild all but it seems that nothing is updated. The project is still compiled and built with the very old source codes.

I tried to click clean all the project and rebuild all again. But sometimes it works, sometimes not

What is the kind of problem I'm having??

Edit 01:
I originally want to do version control. That is I copy the whole project folder or copy several source files for different versions (I usually do this in MS Visual Studio). However, in Qt SDK, this seems not work i.e. the new copied project with updated codes still behaves the same with the original project

Edit 02: my compilation output. This time, I tried both "clean project" and "clean all" and then "rebuild all" but still not work

[image]

Edit 03: this is a new clue for this problem, I've just found strange things from the compilation output:

[image]

This directory is where the project is compiled and run. However, the project currently opened in Qt SDK is not from this directory but:

**...**\Projects\Qt\GUI_from_code_v30**...**

which means that when I copied the whole project to create new version, the configurations in compiler/project file/.. (I'm not sure) was not updated and therefore still point to the old folder and source codes.

then, what can I do now to fix this??

Comment: Are you sure, that the source files, you make changes in, are actually in the project? Because as it is, that makes no sense to me.

Comment: so.. you mean there isn't such a error in Qt environment??

Comment: "but it seems that nothing is updated. The project is still compiled and built with the very old source codes." Either nothing has changed so it doesn't build, or your changes result in a program that functions no differently - which is it?

Comment: I meant that my changes are updated in the source codes and the project is still compiled without error. But it functions no differently (similar to the unchanged source codes)

Comment: Have the time stamps changed on the binaries?  What if you put a big `cout` message in `main()` - does it appear in the console?  Can you post the last few lines of the compilation output?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, start using version control.  You should have that setup right after you install a compiler.  Taking 30mins to lean the basics of Git is going to save you hours of copying files and trying to figure out which files you are editing.

Secondly, QtCreater creates a folder to do some of its work in look for a folder below where you think you are working with the name of -build-desktop.  Chances are with all your copies, that Qt is copying into the same folder for each of them.

Thirdly, triple check which files you are actually updating, we've all made a quick edit to something which we've thought was something else.  Version control cures this as it provides an audit trail.

My personally preference is to use the command line to compile and check-in, it grants more control and lets you see what's going on under the hood.  Which hopefully you'll learn from.

Comment: thank you for your guides! I will take time to investigate this. Still, currently compiling from cmd line and version control i.e. Git are brandnew to me